# Apache redirect username to profile page conflict

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write redirect rules which will redirect usernames to profiles pages. The problem is I don't want to use extra parameter to determine that current url is for user. If I use `example.com/user/test` pattern then there is no problem. But I want to use `example.com/test` pattern.
The problem is also other pages uses this pattern beside user profile. For ex. `example.com/messages`. But these other pages are only a few. Hard coded exceptions should be fine on redirect rules.
Here is what I use for redirecting.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=profile&username=$1 [L]
```

But for urls like `/messages/, /login/, /settings/` I want to use this rule.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Another problem when I remove ending slash from first redirect rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=profile&username=$1 [L]
```

Like this, redirect loop happens. Actually I don't want to have ending slash but I fixed temporarily by adding it. 
I am not sure if this affects other redirect rules but also I want to redirect `index.php` to ``.
To sum everything up I am listing what I am trying to do.

```
example.com/index.php                             =>  example.com
example.com/index.php?page=messages               =>  example.com/messages
example.com/index.php?page=options                =>  example.com/options
example.com/index.php?page=profile&username=test  =>  example.com/test
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/messages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/logout
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/options
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/deposit
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/profile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=view-profile&username=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```